# Adding items to document library in Sharepoint 2013 Preview

Tags: document-library, sharepoint-online

I'm trying to programmatically add an item to a document library in the Sharepoint 2013 Preview that comes with Office 365. I've managed to add an item by using the code fragment below (from a provider-hosted app in C#).

However I can't seem to find an example for doing the same thing with a document library (neither in MSDN documentation nor with Google).

```
var creationInformation = new ListItemCreationInformation();
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem listItem = list.AddItem(creationInformation);
listItem.FieldValues["Foo"] = "Bar";
listItem.Update();
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

I'd be very glad if someone could give me some hints regarding this problem. I'm not exclusively interested in a C# solution, if you know how to do it with JavaScript or via REST API then I'd be happy to hear about that as well. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With C# you can do it this way -

```
SPFolder doclib = web.Folders["Document Library"];
web.AllowUnsafeUpdates=true; 
doclib.Files.Add(filename, bytestream_ofthe_file);
```

this is one simple snippet, not the complete solution, you can easily get the bytestream of a file with C#. It's better to mark AllowUnsafeUpdate to true just to avoid some issues, make it false later.

I am not that much sure about REST API, and with the help of javascript from client side - it's little bit tricky to get the bytestream, otherwise it can be done with calling service from js also

Edit: Here's a working snippet:

```
List documentLibrary = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");
var fileCreationInformation = new FileCreationInformation();
fileCreationInformation.Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\foo.docx");
fileCreationInformation.Url = "foo.docx";
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file = documentLibrary.RootFolder.Files.Add(fileCreationInformation);
clientContext.Load(file);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Check [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sridhara/archive/2010/03/12/uploading-files-using-client-object-model-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx) for more details.

Comment: Thanks @Diptarag - that pushed me in the right direction. I'll add the actual snippet that I used to your answer.